# Installing node-faiss & libomp when deploying

Tags: node.js, vercel, langchain, faiss, langchain-js

I'm building AI website with Chagpt API & langchain. all using node.js, express
now when I want to deploy the project on any platform, like vercel or renderjs I get this error
[image]

telling me that faiss-node library is not installed and I need to install libomp in the project path before deploying.

I already installed faiss-node and everything is working right on my local, but on deployment no. also I tried to deploy without ignoring node_modules folder, Bur the same problem come again.

How can I add libomp to the project path, and how to fix faiss-node is not found.

and thank you guys!

I was deploying the website on many nodejs deployment services, but I find some problems with faiss-node & libomp.